# Verify if password is correct

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, passwords, directoryentry

i need to verify if the password is correct for a user.

i have this code:

```
 private bool checkOldPasswordValid(string password, string username)
    {
        using (DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName + ",computer"))
        {
            entry.Username = username;
            entry.Password = password;

            DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

            searcher.Filter = "(objectclass=user)";
            try
            {
                searcher.FindOne();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

but then directory searcher is not supported with WinNt, so i found another way to loop through all records.

```
 foreach (DirectoryEntry dc in entry.Children)
            {
                // prints the name
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(dc.Name);
            }
```

but this just gets the name and doesnt verify the password.

please help . thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To autenticate against LDAP or WinNT, you need no `DirectorySearcher`. You only need to get the `NativeObject` from your `DirectoryEntry` instance. Here's a code sample that might guide you through the way.

```
public bool Authenticate(string username, string password, string domain) {
    bool authenticated = false;

    using (DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(@"WinNT://" + domain, username, password) {
        try {
            object nativeObject = entry.NativeObject;
            authenticated = true;
        } catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException ex) {
        }
    }

    return authenticated;
}
```

This code will return either a user is authentic or not. Once you can get the NativeObject property using this `DirectoryEntry` class instance, this means that the AD (or local computer) used impersonation to get this object. If you get the object without having a thrown exception, this means that the AD (or local computer) was able to authenticate the impersonnated user.

While you can use the currently authenticated user by specifying no username and password, but only the domain (or local computer), by specifying a username and password, you say you want to use impersonnation, so the security infrastructure will use the given username and password to try to retrieve the `NativeObject` property from this `DirectoryEntry` class instance.

To authenticate against the AD, just replace the `"WinNT://"` for `"LDAP://"`.

Comment: what if the domain is blank sometimes.. will that be a problem?

Comment: The domain can be the local computer name, or the domain from your domain controller using the AD. Normally, the domain should not be blank. I have never tested a blank domain, but I suppose this would cause the `try...catch` to throw. Perhaps would it be best if unit tested, then trying every possible values for each of the parameters.

Comment: DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName, Session["userName"].ToString(), password);

Comment: i did the above. it is verifying even when the password is wrong

Comment: While in ASP.NET, you need to set some settings in the configuration file, if I remember correctly, in order to tell it to use impersonnation. The link provided by Mystere Man tells about this setting you have to set to `true` or `false`. That is a bit different while using ASP.NET. This code works great in the framework security block that I have developed. Maybe the righteous solution for you is a combination of both answers, Mystere Man's and mine.

Comment: Besides, if this is used for an ASP.NET application, then you shouldn't consider to authenticate a local computer's user account. I don't understand that part, but you must know what you're doing, right !? =)

Comment: Then further details are necessary if you require more help on the topic.

Comment: this will work for the domain.. but did not work for user without domain.. so i used logon itself... thanks a lot anyways..

Answer (score 2):

You can use DirectoryEntry itself.

See the example here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316748

Why are you using WinNT:// anyways?

Comment: suppose local acounts are not a part of Active Directory,.. thats why.. but im not sure.. please let me kno if you have more info on this.. thanks

Comment: He's using WinNT:// to authenticate against the computer itself, not the AD.

Comment: @user175084: When using the AD, you're not supposed to manage local accounts. Let me explain. Suppose a user authenticates himself on a local computer, then wish to access a network resource. Even though you authenticated this user as known for local computer, the AD won't let this user get whatever resource he needs if the user is unknown to the AD. That is different if you wish to manage local computer user accounts.

Comment: Well, it would be much simpler to use LogonUser then, would it not?

Comment: i was using log on user to log in.. and was looking for a simple way for this one..

Comment: @Mystere Man: I couldn't agree more! But we can be no judge of what one is doing as we don't know every aspects of the project he's working on, so this is simpler to provide solutions acconrding to what is exposed in the question asked. Besides, perhaps one wishes to impersonnate a service account through a service or an application that has to use some priviledges that the currently logged on user can't access. This is particularly true as Microsoft recommends creating service accounts for "user" that needs to work with specific sensible data, but any regular user shouldn't access.

Comment: @Mystere Man: This link provided doesn't use the `DirectorySearcher` class? I guess so, after having read the article. That is exactly what the op says was not possible to use for a local computer.