# Repeatedly verify that account can log on

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I need a method to verify that an AD account can logon with a given password and is not disabled. As in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3934939/689923), I am trying to use DirectoryEntry to accomplish this:

```
public static bool CanLogon(string userName, string domainPath, string password) {
    try {
        using (new DirectoryEntry(domainPath, userName, password, AuthenticationTypes.Secure)) {                 
            var x = domainEntry.NativeObject; // force binding
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work in the following case:

1. Call the method with correct account parameters, so the method returns true.
2. Change the password of that account or disable the account.
3. Call the method again with exactly the same parameters. The method still returns true even though it should now return false.

I would be grateful for any solution that works for this case.

---

Analysis:

- The problem also occurs in domains with only one DC, so it's not a replication problem.
- If Step 1 is omitted, Step 3 correctly returns false, so this seems to be a caching problem, despite the call to entry.NativeObject, which is supposed to force a live call into AD.
- If in Step 3 the userName is written with capitalization different from Step 1 (e.g. "John.Doe" vs "john.doe"), Step 3 correctly returns false, which again indicates a caching problem.

Comment: Yes, Kerberos tickets are cached. Changing a password will not immediately cause the old password to stop functioning, neither will disabling an account immediately propagate to all clients. Inspecting/purging the cache can be done with the `klist` tool. I don't know if the caching can be forcibly bypassed; in theory, authenticating on the domain controller itself should do. Note, however, that your results are *correct*, inasmuch that the account *can actually log on* on that particular machine, for as long as the changes haven't caught up with it.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure ticket caching is to blame in this case since those don't themselves deal with passwords - I may be confusing this with the credential cache of LSASS, and I'm not sure you can interact with that at all. In either case, explicitly authenticating on the domain controller should bypass this, but I don't know how you do that in managed code.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: I tried a logon to the DC with the disabled account between Steps 2 and 3 (which correctly fails). Still, in Step 3 the method returns true.

Comment: Are you executing your code itself on the DC? Forcing a failure on the DC has no effect on other machines. My suggestion is explicitly performing the logon on the DC *in the code*, exactly because the DC has the latest data.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: No, the code is not running (and cannot run) on the DC itself. I was hoping that the call to NativeObject would always contact the DC. But it's only doing that the first time. Subsequent calls with the same parameters are also much faster. Only if I change the capitalization of userName, NativeObject results in a fresh and slow live call.